# Difference between created_at created by mysql expression and PHP laravel

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder if is there any difference between Laravel's `created_at` and `updated_at` and mysql default DATETIME field value.

With MySQL I can use `Default` clause expression to auto insert current timestamp for created_at.

> The default value specified in a DEFAULT clause can be a literal constant or an expression.
> -- As of [mysql 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)

And on Laravel, when I can use

```
public $timestamps = true;
```

It inserts the created_at in mysql.

So what is difference between them, and which one is better, faster?

Comment: Will you actually use either column in a query?

Comment: *which one is better* MySQL's `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: @Akina Could you explain more, or maybe a link to it?

Comment: While using MySQL's feature you do not need to include both this column and its value into the query. Less traffic, less point of possible errors, no de-sync between diferent clients, especially when their local clocks are adjusted wrongly.

Comment: Thank for your answer!

Comment: DB time / Client time they aren't necessarily the same.  Imagine you are in New York and your server is in Australia ... if you rely on DB time the created at timestamp will have a value that when eventually given back to the client will most probably be wrong ...